# JSFiddle using external jQuery/jQueryUI js & css files not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am attempting to import the official Wordpress versions of jQuery & jQuery UI libraries, in order to simulate a working Wordpress installation.

I only wanted to make a few simple tweaks to a slider because when I use the framework(s) provided by JSFiddle, they are of a newer version than the ones shipped with version 4.8 of Wordpress. And to top it off, it seems to act differently when it comes to updating the slider's range width, with the newer versions of jQuery supported by JSFiddle. Hence, I tried to simulate an actual Wordpress installation, but it doesn't seem to be showing anything whatsoever.

I've tried changing the JS settings from "onLoad" to "No wrap - in head" similar to the way Wordpress handles it, but to no avail.

It's very possible I'm missing something that's right in front of my face, wouldn't be the first time. It may not even be possible b/c of the way Wordpress combines the 2 js files when enqueuing them (i.e. you only need to enqueue jQuery in order to access the UI functions), etc. But I wasn't certain about that, so to test that theory, I created a separate fiddle altogether that doesn't use any external resources from Wordpress and only uses the ones supplied by Google.

Here are both fiddles, the first one is using Wordpress resources and the second, Google.

1. https://jsfiddle.net/u09334y7/15/

```js
$('.ae-slider').slider({
    range: 'min',
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    animate: false,
    slide: function (event, ui) {});
    $('#progress').html($('.ae-slider').slider('value'));
```

2. https://jsfiddle.net/rdmcr7u6/1/

```js
$('.ae-slider').slider({
    range: 'min',
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    animate: false,
    slide: function (event, ui) {});
    $('#progress').html($('.ae-slider').slider('value'));
```

Comment: `no-wrap in head` means the script is inserted in the head, without any DOM ready handlers. You have to either add DOM ready handlers to your script, or use one of the other options in JSFiddle that loads the scripts **after** the elements are available in the DOM

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/u09334y7/18/

Comment: @adeneo Correct. However, in your example, it appears you're using JSFiddle's jQuery framework rather than the external resources I attached. I know that it works with the supplied framework, but I am trying to make it work with the external resources I put in my example. I've used your fiddle and put my resources back in, and used the document.ready function like you mentioned. Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u09334y7/24/ As you can see, it still doesn't work.

Comment: There are depencies for those UI scripts, for instance all of them require the ui.core script, and the slider probably require the ui,widget and maybe more.